# Does google AutoML Vision have batch prediction and how to use it?

Tags: python, vision, automl, google-cloud-automl

First, I got a model trained, which is kinda cool. 
I am also able - after some headache and confusion about why the model is in us-central - to make single API predictions.

I am wondering is it possible to do batch predictions also?

Cheers

Comment: It depends on which AutoML you are using, if you are using AutoML NLP it has batch prediction [here](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.automl.v1beta1#google.cloud.automl.v1beta1.BatchPredictRequest). I don't think AutoML vision has batch prediction yet.

Comment: Alright, very unfortunate :/